# Vertically stack date range filters in Telerik GridDateTimeColumn

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

In Telerik ASP.NET Ajax:

```
GridDateTimeColumn c = new GridDateTimeColumn();
c.EnableRangeFiltering = true;
```

This adds a date range filter with "From:" and "To:" calendar control inputs. The controls are aligned horizontally:

```
From: _____ [CAL] To: ____ [CAL] [FILTER]
```

Is there some way that I can stack the controls vertically? Like:

```
From: ______ [CAL]
TO:   ______ [CAL] [FILTER]
```

Currently the horizontal inline alignment increases the column width significantly and affects the user experience with the grid.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a hacky solution, but a solution nonetheless...

```
protected void rgMyGrid_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    var fi = e.Item as GridFilteringItem;
    if (fi == null) return;
    var litTo = fi["DateCol"].Controls[3] as LiteralControl;
    if (litTo != null) litTo.Text = "<br /><span style=\"padding-right:17px\">To:</span>";
}
```

You'll obviously need to add an OnItemCreated event handler to your grid definition.

`DateCol` is the UniqueName of your `GridDateTimeColumn`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't really work for me as I don't know the names of all my columns (e.g. `fi["DateCol"]`) in advance. Any way to hack your hack to just apply it to all columns that have a date range filter in them?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the UniqueName of your GridDateTimeColumns in advance, the extremely hacky code below should do the trick :)

```
protected void rgMyGrid_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    var fi = e.Item as GridFilteringItem;
    if (fi == null) return;

    foreach (var litTo in from Control c in fi.Controls where c.Controls.Count == 6 select (LiteralControl) c.Controls[3])
            litTo.Text = "<br /><span style=\"padding-right:17px\">To:</span>";          
}
```

The key here is knowing that there are 6 controls that make up the range filtering control collection.